Dimension of Kernel for Linear Map on Tensor Product Space
Let $U = \mathbb{R}^{d_1 \times d_2}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^{d_2 \times d_3}$ be spaces of matrices. Consider the linear map:
$$T: U \otimes V \to \mathbb{R}^{d_1 \times d_3}$$
defined by
$$T(A \otimes B) = AB, \quad \text{where } A \in U, B \in V.$$
I'm looking to compute the dimension of the kernel space of $T$, denoted $\ker(T)$.  The fact that this map is defined on a tensor product space is throwing me off. Thank you in advance!

What have you tried or thought about? How do you compute nullity in non tensor product situations and what's the obstacle here?

Hi blargoner, if it is not a tensor product situation, the kernel of a matrix $A$ can be obtained by Gaussian elimination, am I right?
